# I/O past end of record on unformatted file

Tags: io, binary, fortran

I am using Specfem3d package. This package writes some files in unformatted .bin files.
there is another program to read produced files. But when I run that code to read unformatted binary files, it returns me the following error:

At line 337 of file src/tomography/read_model.f90 (unit = 40, file = 'topo/proc000012_external_mesh.bin')
Fortran runtime error: I/O past end of record on unformatted file

There was a python code to check file. It results following output (maybe helpful info):

```
scan type <q ( little endian 8 byte header) invalid header size  34359738368004  exceeds file size  82468068
scan type >q ( big endian 8 byte header) invalid header size  288230377227485184  exceeds file size  82468068
scan type <i ( little endian 4 byte header)

read record 1 size 4

read record 2 size 4

read record 3 size 4

read record 4 size 4000000

read record 5 size 2125764

read record 6 size 2125764

read record 7 size 2125764

read record 8 size 32000

read record 9 size 4

successfully read  69  records with unformatted fortran header type <i

scan type >i ( big endian 4 byte header) unmatched header
```

What should I do? :((

Part of code that should read file is:

```
open(IIN,file='proc.bin',status='old',form='unformatted',iostat=ier)

nglob=531441

NGLLX=5

NGLLy=5

NGLLz=5

nspec=8000

read(IIN) ival

allocate(ibool(NGLLX,NGLLY,NGLLZ,NSPEC))

allocate(x(NGLOB),y(NGLOB),z(NGLOB))

read(IIN) ibool(:,:,:,1:nspec) !!!!error occurs in this line

print*,ibool

  read(IIN) x(1:nglob)

  read(IIN) y(1:nglob)

  read(IIN) z(1:nglob)

  close(IIN)
```

EDIT:
The original safe function is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3edx8i7nd8n177x/save_arrays_solver.F90?dl=0).

Comment: From the python output it seems like you should first read 3 integers (not just the one `ival`?), then 1 large array (ibool?, correct type?), then 3 large arrays (x,y,x?).

Answer (score 0):

Now with the limited amount of information that you're giving, I can't make a definitive assessment.

That said, the output of the python script suggests that there are 3 small records (3 4-byte records, maybe integer?) before the large record.

But you are only reading the first one (`ival`) before you try to read the large one with a million elements (`ibool`).

I would recommend that you make more effort to understand the structure of the file, what data is stored where, and how it is written.

If you're unable to do so, I would try to read records 2 and 3 into single integer variables, then try again. But I'd be very thorough in checking that the data is valid when you do that.

Edit: You have given links to your code in an answer (hint, don't do that, edit the question), and here you can see what I mean:

```
open(unit=IOUT,file=trim(filename),status='unknown',action='write',form='unformatted',iostat=ier)
....
write(IOUT) nspec
write(IOUT) nglob
write(IOUT) nspec_irregular

write(IOUT) ibool
```

You can see that `ibool` is the **4th** record to be written. So you have to read it as the **4th**, something like:

```
open(...)
read(IIN) ival
read(IIN) ival
read(IIN) ival
allocate(ibool(...))
read(IIN) ibool
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. This part of code is a brief of main code just for reading files. I add two other lines to read that parameter you mentioned but still noting changed.